# Combine value from two rows per column: CONCAT or SPLIT/JOIN?

Tags: join, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've tried multiple variations of this formula only to get the same result.

```
=TRANSPOSE({FILTER('tasks-Groups'!B1:1,'tasks-Groups'!B1:1<>"");FILTER('tasks-Groups'!B2:2,'tasks-Groups'!B1:1<>"")})
```

```
=TRANSPOSE({'tasks-Groups'!B1:1;'tasks-Groups'!B2:2})
```

```
={TRANSPOSE('tasks-Groups'!B1:1),TRANSPOSE('tasks-Groups'!B2:2)}
```

But these formulas all print to two columns.  What I'd ultimately like to achieve is, in a single column:

```
B1:B2

C1:C2

D1:D2...
```

I thought I just needed to concatenate the two ranges, but now I'm beginning to think I need to use `SPLIT`/`JOIN`, but not familiar with those functions at all.

Here's [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rp06YC4JtIu4KsoiciN9OASq5HSaCkjVfrN5wo8mqP0/edit#gid=267416160&range=A2) (Sheet49!A2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to join two columns do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A&":"&B1:B)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: What if there are multiple columns and some are blank? :-)

Comment: This is what I'm doing for now, but thought there's bound to be a trimmed down version. `=ARRAYFORMULA(J2:J&IF(K2:K<>"", ", "&K2:K,)&IF(L2:L<>"", ", "&L2:L,))`